# Calling agg without first calling groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a function similar to `agg`, that doesn't require a `groupby` call first?

For example, I often already have an agg map written, and want to evaluate the map for the entire table.

So I want to change

`data = data.groupby("key").agg({"foo1":"sum", "foo2":"mean"})`

to

`data = data.agg({"foo1":"sum", "foo2":"mean"})`

I currently do this by inserting a fake key, and then aggregating on that. But that's a hack. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** as @root proposed in the comment, it would be easier and more elegant to group by `np.repeat(0, len(df))`:

```
In [5]: df.groupby(np.repeat(0, len(df))).agg({'A':'sum', 'B':'mean', 'C':'min'})
Out[5]:
      B    A   C
0  42.9  484  21
```

**OLD answer:**

assuming that you have a numeric index which is always `>= 0`:

```
In [139]: df.groupby(df.index >= 0, as_index=False).agg({'A':'sum', 'B':'mean', 'C':'min'})
Out[139]:
     A     B   C
0  484  42.9  21
```

or assuming that your index doesn't have any `NaN`s

```
In [140]: df.groupby(df.index==df.index, as_index=False).agg({'A':'sum', 'B':'mean', 'C':'min'})
Out[140]:
     A     B   C
0  484  42.9  21
```

if your index can have NaN's use the following trick:

```
In [160]: df.groupby(pd.notnull(df.index) | pd.isnull(df.index), as_index=False).agg({'A':'sum', 'B':'mean', 'C':'min'})
Out[160]:
     A     B   C
0  484  42.9  21
```

Data:

```
In [138]: df
Out[138]:
    A   B   C
0  34  45  68
1  71  62  61
2  39  51  33
3  38  62  27
4  16  39  21
5  94  41  41
6  14  11  41
7  76  40  29
8  44  34  70
9  58  44  68
```

Comment: Couldn't you just group by `np.repeat(1, len(df))` or an equivalent list comprehension, without needing to worry about the index?

Comment: No problem, I wouldn't have thought of it without seeing your answer!  After a little more thought, maybe `np.repeat(0, len(df))` would be slightly better, so the resulting index is `0` instead of `1`, and thus more consistent with the usual conventions.

Comment: @root, yes, thanks again! It looks more conventional. Alternatively we can do: `df.groupby(np.repeat(1, len(df)), as_index=False).agg({'A':'sum', 'B':'mean', 'C':'min'})` - `as_index=False` will do the thing